# Should I use 'ser' or 'estar' to talk about when an event takes place?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, cópulas, tiempo

I'm trying to say that recurring events are on certain days.  Since its an event, should it be a phrase with **ser**?  Or since the events fall on certain days, do I use **estar**?

Comment: You could clarify what you are trying to say with an example.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with **ser**:

> El jueves **era** el día que cenábamos pizza cuando yo era pequeño.
>
> Los jueves **eran** los días que cenábamos pizza.

We use **ser** to refer when a event takes place.

> El domingo **es** el día de ir a misa.

Answer (score 2):

Events took place on a determinate moment, but as far as you know that this is inmutable, you should use "Ser". You only can use "Estar" in certain cases when you know that the event is susceptible to change it's schedule.

> La reunión **está** programada para el viernes.
>
> La reunión **es** el viernes.

Both phrases are equally valid, however, the first one implies that it could be changed. On this cases you always need a second verb to help you: "está programada", "está prevista", "está marcada"

The same is applicable for recurring events.

> Los partidos de fútbol sala **son** los jueves.
>
> Los partidos de fútbol sala **están** puestos los jueves.

The second one implies that it is susceptible to change. The first one does not. It could change anyway, but when you use "ser" you are stating that, to your knowledge, this is something that is not going to change.

Comment: Great answer, but I think I disagree that we use **estar** when the event is susceptible of being changed. Estar + participle (estar programada, estar puesta) is a different construct. It is more about **ser** being used to explain _they happen this or that day_ and **estar + participle** used to say _this has been done to the event, in order to schedule it_

Answer (score 1):

If you want that some events happen a certain day, you have to use the word "ser".

The word "estar" is only used to declare a particular state or a process(time, position, condition, etc). However you can also use a second verb after "estar" that works as an adjective to be able to substitute the verb "estar". For example:

> Los partidos de fútbol sala son los jueves.
>
> Los partidos de fútbol sala están puestos los jueves.

In the second sentence, "estar" is remarking the verb (adjetivized) "puestos", for that reason we can use it in spite of ser, but estar only indicates a state.

Answer (score 0):

What I've heard is the verb "caer", but this may be local usage.

> Los partidos de fútbol caen los jueves.

Answer (score 0):

Se emplea "ser".

Ejemplo:

> "La fiesta será el sábado"
>     "El juego fue el viernes"

Comment: You should explain a little bit more why, since you are not adding anything new to what already has been posted.